# unable to import scikit-learn into NX Open API

Tags: multithreading, scikit-learn

I am trying to import sklearn.cluster and scipy.spatial into a 3D CAD/CAM modeling program called NX.

I created a virtual environment with Anaconda for Python 3.3.2 (conda create -n py33) and I installed sklearn via conda. I am using Windows 7 on an Intel 64 bit machine. For the most part, I have been able to use numpy methods and attributes successfully although some (`np.array_equiv`)will lock up NX.

When I run a python file with `import sklearn.cluster`, it will crash NX. I have not used any sklearn classes or methods yet. The `import` line alone will crash NX. I also face a similar issue with `import scipy.spatial`. I did not use any scipy.spatial methods or classes.

According to the documentation, putting a comment `#nx:threaded` at the very top of the python file should resolve the issue but it has not.

It is my understanding that Python 3.2+ has a new GIL implementation. Importing threaded extension modules into NX can be problematic as the documentation below states

https://docs.plm.automation.siemens.com/tdoc/nx/10.0.3/release_notes/#uid:xid385122

*Running threaded extension modules with Python
The embedded Python interpreter in NX runs Python scripts using subinterpreter threads to isolate the execution environments of different scripts that are running simultaneously. For example, you can use the startup script, utilize user exits, and explicitly run a journal in a session. Running each of these scripts in a separate subinterpreter keeps each of these environments separate from each other to avoid possible illegal access and collisions.
However, this approach has some drawbacks. There are a few third-party extension modules (non-NXOpen extension modules, such as matplotlib) that use C threads to perform operations. These extension modules could be imported safely, but when a function is called that starts a C thread, the subinterpreter hangs or crashes. These extensions run safely only in the main interpreter thread. Unfortunately, Python does not provide a safe way to run such extension modules in subinterpreter threads and does not provide any way to switch from a subinterpreter thread to the main interpreter thread when a script is already executing.*

*To support such threaded extension modules, NX must know if a Python script is using any of these modules before preparing its interpreter. So if the script is using these kinds of threaded extension modules or importing a module that is using threaded extension modules directly or indirectly, you should add a comment with the text nx:threaded anywhere in the first three lines. For example:*

```
# nx:threaded

# some comments nx:threaded some comments

# some comments
# nx:threaded
# some comments
```

*This instructs NX to prepare its embedded Python interpreter to run the script in the main thread instead of the subinterpreter thread to avoid a possible problem. Pure Python threads do not have those kinds of problems with subinterpreters and should be used without this extra comment. This comment could be added to any Python script whether it is a startup script, a user exit script, or a normal journal.
Do not use this comment unnecessarily. It runs all the scripts in the main interpreter thread and may exhibit some unusual behavior, such as illegal data access and object deallocation. Use this comment only when threaded extension modules are imported and used.*

Answer (score 1):

Try #nx: threaded token.
It may happen that some extension modules start native threads at the time of import itself. Somehow, sklearn.cluster import is interfering or modifying data of embedded subinterpreter state. The same problem could be seen in numpy too. The documentation might not be 100% correct. I think adding "nx: threaded" token should solve your problem.

Comment: do you mean `#nx: threaded` or `#nx: threaded token`? I have already tried `#nx: threaded` and it did not work. I think you are right though about the subinterpreter

Comment: please see comment above